WFS GetFeature outputformat
If I execute a WFS GetFeature request on a QGIS Server, specifying outputformat=application/json and srsname=EPSG:32633, I obtain result in EPSG:4326; if I omit outputformat to obtain result in GML format, the coordinate are returned in requested CRS. I have see that on WMS GetFeatureInfo request there are similar issue (https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/32326) that are marked as resolved to return coordinate in CRS requested from client.
I'm asking data in JSON format, not in GeoJSON (that has application/geo+json as format and which requires that coordinates to be geographical).

It seems that for WFS service of QGIS Server MIME types application/json and application/geo+json are synonyms and there are even more of them. See "
Server be nice and accept geojson mime type variants" https://github.com/elpaso/QGIS/commit/57dda3357148e9f5f953d0c4eb53ab13c796344e
I recommend staying with GML if you need data in srsname=EPSG:32633.
